# Three lines menu button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как в данный код вставить иконку меню гамбургер или три линии?

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

     <! -- start collapsed -->  
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button
        type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_navbar" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
     </div> <! -- / collapsed navbar-->  

        <! -- start un-collapsed -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
             id="main_navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="tasks.html">Tasks</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  <! --  / un-collapsed navbar-->
    </div>    <! -- / container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: А почему бы Вам просто не взять изначально код из семплов bootstrap и просто убрать все лишнее? (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)... там и гамбургер есть...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для кнопки с полосками надо добавить следующий код в блок `<div class="navbar-header">`, но лучше всё же разобраться предметно, а не использовать код рандомными кусками.

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

Comment: Кнопка появилась но при ее нажатии ничего не происходит

Comment: @Edgar Kiljak чтобы работало выпадающее меню, надо подключить jquery-библиотеку. она идет в архиве со всеми файлами, который скачивается с главного сайт bootstrap